# wrapping plain javascript object in jquery $({})

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fragment of code from a book I am reading. And want to understand what `$({})` means and what is its use exactly.

I tried searching on several search engines and even on SO. `$({})` wasn't a search-friendly term.

```
    var Events = {
       bind: function(){
          if ( !this.o ) this.o = $({});
          this.o.bind.apply(this.o, arguments);
       },

       trigger: function(){
          if ( !this.o ) this.o = $({});
          this.o.trigger.apply(this.o, arguments);
       }
    };
```

I did find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587372/what-does-mean-in-jquery) about `$([])` but I don't think it is quite the same thing.

Comment: Hey @Robin Maben, your edit just put the answer in the title ! I'm not sure you did wrong, so I won't revert, but I wonder.

Comment: It's a more likelier search term with somebody asking a why/what. Hence, the edit. Searching  [`what does mean in jquery`](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20does%20mean%20in%20jquery) brings up the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587372/what-does-mean-in-jquery) to which this one is marked as a "related question". So I thought both titles need not be obscure since one would lead to another anyway. Am I making sense? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're just wrapping a basic javascript object as a jQuery one.

From [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) :

> #### Working With Plain Objects
>
> At present, the only operations supported
>   on plain JavaScript objects wrapped in jQuery are:
>   .data(),.prop(),.bind(), .unbind(), .trigger() and .triggerHandler().
>   The use of .data() (or any method requiring .data()) on a plain object
>   will result in a new property on the object called
>   jQuery{randomNumber} (eg. jQuery123456789).
>
> ```
> // define a plain object
> var foo = {foo:'bar', hello:'world'};
>
> // wrap this with jQuery
> var $foo = $(foo);
>
> // test accessing property values
> var test1 = $foo.prop('foo'); // bar
>
> // test setting property values
> $foo.prop('foo', 'foobar');
> var test2 = $foo.prop('foo'); // foobar
>
> // test using .data() as summarized above
> $foo.data('keyName', 'someValue'); console.log($foo); // will now contain a
>                                                       // jQuery{randomNumber}
>                                                       // property
>
> // test binding an event name and triggering
> $foo.bind('eventName', function (){
>     console.log('eventName was called');
> });
>
> $foo.trigger('eventName'); // logs 'eventName was called'
> ```
>
> Should
>   .trigger('eventName') be used, it will search for an 'eventName'
>   property on the object and attempt to execute it after any attached
>   jQuery handlers are executed. It does not check whether the property
>   is a function or not. To avoid this behavior,
>   .triggerHandler('eventName') should be used instead.
>
> ```
> $foo.triggerHandler('eventName'); // also logs 'eventName was called'
> ```

Here's a (not really useful) example :

```
​var a =$({});
a.data('b', 3);
console.log(a.data('b')); // this prints 3
```

If you keep your object created with `$({})`, you may use it as callee for `data`, `bind`, and so on. This is probably the minimal non DOM keepable jquery object you can make.

Comment: That is what I thought, but why would anyone do that? What is the difference vs a plain $()?

Comment: Because if you want to bind (or use data) to an object, you can't use `$()` but you may keep a reference on an instance created with `$({})`.

Comment: `$()` has different results in different versions of jQuery. Older versions would assume you meant `$(document)`, newer versions assume you meant `$([])`

Answer (score 1):

this really has more to do with javascript syntax than jQuery.

`{}` is for objects like so:

```
 //makes an empty object
 var myObject = {}; 

 //makes an object containing 'foo' and 'bar' as 'firstItem' and 'secondItem'
 var myObject = { firstItem : foo, secondItem : bar };
```

`[]` is for arrays like so:

```
 //makes a blank array
 var myArray = [];

 //makes an array containing 'foo' and 'bar' at postions 0 and 1
 var myArray = [foo, bar];
```

`()` is for functions (which jQuery generally is). This is abit more complicated because it can have multiple meanings.

```
 //running an existing function
 myFunction();

 //running an anonymous function
 (function(){  
    //doSomething }
 )();

 //running a function with an argument
 myFunction(arg);
```

jQuery is generally just a function called `$` instead of `myFunction` so...

```
 //runs jQuery as a function on 'arg'
 $(arg);
```

The argument you pass jQuery can be almost anything. If you pass it a string like `'#myDiv'` jQuery will use that argument as a selector to get an element from the html. If you pass it something else like an object or an array, it can still do some things with it like: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ as @dystroy said.

So `$({})` is the same as `$(myBlankObject)`, for example:

```
var myBlankObject = {};
$(myBlankObject);
//is the same as
$({});
```

and

```
var myObjectWithStuff = { firstItem :  foo, secondItem : bar };
$(myObjectWithStuff);
//is the same as
$({ firstItem :  foo, secondItem : bar });
```

`$('selector')` works. `$({'selector'})` or `$(['selector'])` does not, because you are not passing jQuery a string, but another data type.